# Bootstrap table doesn't work after i append it with JQ

Tags: jquery, html

I am using bootstrap-table from here - http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/

So, here is my code:

```
<table id="control-table" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="name" data-search="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-formatter="id">№</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-editable="true" data-field="name">Название</th>
            <th data-field="action" data-formatter="controlActions" data-events="controlEvents" data-valign="middle" data-align="center" data-halign="left">Действия</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

If i put it in my HTML file, it works with styles... 
But if i try to append it with JQ like this:

```
    $('#aaa').append('\
        <table id="control-table" data-toggle="table" data-sort-name="name"\ data-search="true">\
        <thead>\
        <tr>\
        <th data-sortable="true" data-formatter="id">№</th>\
        <th data-sortable="true" data-editable="true" data-field="name">Название</th>\
        <th data-field="action" data-formatter="controlActions" data-events="controlEvents" data-valign="middle" data-align="center" data-halign="left">Действия</th>\
        </tr>\
        </thead>\
        </table>\
        ')
```

It doesn't work, it just writes me the names of tables and that's all... No styles.

Comment: Not entirely sure without a working example, but you probably need to re-initialize bootstrap-tables after appending, by calling $('#table').bootstrapTable({ etc.. (see the bottom of the docs)

Comment: I can't find in google how to write it normaly

Comment: try to call $('#tableID').bootstrapTable() after appending

Answer (score 0):

$('#tableID').bootstrapTable() after appending - THis will work. 
Thanks to - niorad. (His profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/5774727/niorad)

Comment: it doesnt work for me after i append the row and call the $('#tableID').bootstrapTable()